# create horizenta scroll with map .toList()

Tags: flutter

I am trying to scroll horizontally but it doesn't work it just scrolls vertically
I wrap the widget with singleScrollview and give it a direction horizontal but this also not works
here is my code
`

```
                                                          Expanded(
                                                          child: Column(
                                                            children: [
                                                              Column(
                                                                children:
                                                                    etaDetails
                                                                        .asMap()
                                                                        .map((i,
                                                                            value) {
                                                                          return MapEntry(
                                                                              i,
                                                                              StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(
                                                                                  stream: fdb.onValue,
                                                                                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot event) {

                                                                                    return InkWell(
                                                                                      onTap: () {
                                                                                        
                                                                                      },
                                                                                      child: Container(
                                                                                        width: 100,
                                                                                        height: 80,
                                                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(media.width * 0.03),
                                                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                              
                                                                                        ),
                                                                                        child: Text("data")
                                                                                      ),
                                                                                    );
                                                                                  }));
                                                                        })
                                                                        .values
                                                                        .toList(),
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        )
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Change `Column` with `Row` widget,

```
 Expanded(
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Row(
                                                            children:
                                                                etaDetails
                                                                    .asMap()
                                                                    .map((i,
                                                                        value) {
                                                                      return MapEntry(
                                                                          i,
                                                                          StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(
                                                                              stream: fdb.onValue,
                                                                              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot event) {

                                                                                return InkWell(
                                                                                  onTap: () {
                                                                                    
                                                                                  },
                                                                                  child: Container(
                                                                                    width: 100,
                                                                                    height: 80,
                                                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(media.width * 0.03),
                                                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                          
                                                                                    ),
                                                                                    child: Text("data")
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                );
                                                                              }));
                                                                    })
                                                                    .values
                                                                    .toList(),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                         

                       )
```